# How do you get the max value of a given column of a 2D std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I know how to get the max value of the row of a 2D std::vector as follows:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> a = {{ 1, 45, 54}, {71, 76, 12 }, {74451, 756, 125 }};}

std::cout << " The max value of row 0 is: " << *max_element(begin(a[0]), end(a[0]));
```

How do you do call max_element to get the max value of a 2D vector column instead? (without copying the column into a 1D vector)

Thanks!

Comment: In general, don’t use vectors of vectors to implement 2D vectors

Comment: what happens if one of the rows has a different length?

Comment: You can just use a for loop to go through that column of the array.

Comment: Do you want an iterator to the element or are you good with just the value? Can `a` be empty? Can any of the inner vectors be empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is provide `std::max_element` with a user-defined *comparator* that compares each `std::vector<int>` in `a` by the values in the desired column to search.

Like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> a = {{ 1, 45, 54}, {71, 76, 12 }, {74451, 756, 125 }};

std::cout << " The max value of row 0 is: " << *max_element(begin(a[0]), end(a[0])) << '\n';

auto max_col_0 = (*std::max_element(begin(a), end(a), [](auto& a, auto& b){ return a[0] < b[0]; }))[0];
auto max_col_1 = (*std::max_element(begin(a), end(a), [](auto& a, auto& b){ return a[1] < b[1]; }))[1];

std::cout << " The max value of col 0 is: " << max_col_0 << '\n';
std::cout << " The max value of col 1 is: " << max_col_1 << '\n';
```

Here the llambda function is called with two `std::vector<int>`objects to compare and you need to compare the values in the given column you are searching. Resolving the `auto` types will give this for the *comparator*:

```
[](std::vector<int>& a, std::vector<int>& b){ return a[1] < b[1]; }
```

The `std::max_element` function calls the comparator with each of *vector* `a`'s stored *vectors* so that the relevant column in each vector can be compared for which is the lesser.

The returned iterator is to the winning `std::vector<int>` from which you need to extract the winning column after dereferencing the iterator.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say the column for which you need to find the max value is `c`. You can then just iterate through that column.

```
int m = a[0][c]; // initialize the maximum to be value of column c in first row.
for(int i = 1; i < a.size(); i++){ // loop through all rows.
    m = max(m, a[i][c]);
}
cout<<"Maximum value in column "<<c<<" is "<<m<<endl;
```

Comment: What happens if `a` is empty or if the first inner vector in `a` is empty? This also doesn't return an iterator to the found element which it seems OP wants.

Comment: This is a normal approach to find the max element of a particular column. I think the OP has a 2D array of non-zero constant size. Also, the OP wants actual max value not an iterator to the max value.

Comment: With `vector`s I wouldn't be so sure. Since both the inner and outer container is a vector, I'd expect a robust algorithm to handle the case any of them are empty - but you are perhaps correct.

Comment: I think my eyes are too tired and I think your assumption is ok.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `std::max_element` you can use a vector of vectors iterator to iterate over any *column* and find the max value, something like:

```
int maxValue(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &a, size_t col)
{
    int max_value = 0; //assuming non negative values in the vector

    try
    {
        for (auto it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); it++)
            max_value = it->at(col) > max_value ? it->at(col) : max_value;
    }
    catch (std::out_of_range &e)
    {
        return -1; // or whatever you'd like
    }

    return max_value;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> a = {{1, 45, 54}, {71, 76, 12}, {74451, 756, 125}};

    std::cout << maxValue(a, 0) << " "; // first column
    std::cout << maxValue(a, 1) << " "; // second column
    std::cout << maxValue(a, 2) << " "; // third column
    std::cout << maxValue(a, 3);        // out of range
}
```

Output:

```
74451 756 125 -1
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo lol, that could have gotten me into trouble, ty.

Comment: You're welcome! I was about to write "typofix, but not a.s amusing anymore" :-)